# How to extract words next to a string using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

```
9.DATUM DER ERTEILUNG DER ZULASSUNG/VERLÄNGERUNG DER ZULASSUNG
10.STAND DER INFORMATION
Juni 2019
Rezeptpflicht/Apothekenpflicht
Rezept- und apothekenpflichtig, wiederholte Abgabe verboten.
```

This is my text and I am trying to extract dates which are always after `STAND DER INFORMATION`. `Juni 2019` in this example text above.

I have tried string split method but that doesn't work for me as I just need the dates.

Comment: add the code you have written.

Comment: If you want to use a regexp, use a positive lookbehind. But it might be simpler to split the string into lines, search for the line with the search string, then use the next element.

Comment: Is the date you are searching for always on the next line? Is it only a single date on a single line? If so, I would iterate over the lines in your input until you find one that contains "STAND DER INFORMATION" then get the date from the next line.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text has **STAND DER INFORMATION** prior to date as illustrated you can use the following.

**Code**

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?<=STAND DER INFORMATION\s)\D{3,4}\s\d{4}', s, re.MULTILINE)
```

**Explanation**

```
# s is text string
# <=STAND DER INFORMATION\n - look behind for STAND DER INFORMATION followed by \n
# \D is non-digit (so 3 or 4 non-digits)
# \d digits (so four digit date)
# re.MULTILINE - multiline flag to allow matches across multiple lines
```

**Test**

```
s = """9.DATUM DER ERTEILUNG DER ZULASSUNG/VERLÄNGERUNG DER ZULASSUNG
10.STAND DER INFORMATION
Juni 2019
Rezeptpflicht/Apothekenpflicht
Rezept- und apothekenpflichtig, wiederholte Abgabe verboten."""
dates = re.findall(r'(?<=STAND DER INFORMATION\n)\D{3,4}\s\d{4}', s, re.MULTILINE)
print(dates)
```

**Output**

```
['Juni 2019']
```